# Adding a reference between Eclipse Java projects

Tags: java, eclipse

I have two Java projects in an Eclipse workspace, and I would like to use a class from one of them in the other.

How can I add a reference between them? I'm looking for something like adding a project reference in C#.

Comment: There's no such thing as a "java project". What tools are you using?

Comment: If the OP is using Eclipse there is such thing as a "Java Project"

Comment: @Aaron Eclipse isn't Java and Java isn't Eclipse. A lot of people use other tools.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Assuming you are using Eclipse...

*Right click the project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Projects tab*

...which will allow you to force required projects on the project in questions build path.

Comment: You can also Add Class Folder in Java Build Path if you don't need to add the whole project.

Comment: Very new to eclipse :) very old at .NET :) Thanks!!! I also noticed that if I use the class it automatically adds it for you... Nice!

Comment: What does this actually do? What files is it changing. Update pls.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem but even after adding the project in the aforementioned way it still would not recognize the other project.

Turns out you must create a package, not use "default package" in the inner project, that fixed it.