# Adding huge packages into new projects (Eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse

I have created a builder project that builds alot of charts

This project contains of 4 different packages where each package consists of 2 - 4 classes each.

My question is how can i implement this project with all its classes and use them in my new projects without having to copy all the classes?

Comment: Use Maven and you can always add your builder as a dependency in the new projects.

Comment: This question has been asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4798694/adding-a-reference-between-eclipse-java-projects, please use the search function before posting new questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the builder project to client project's build path or build a jar from your builder project and import it into your client projects.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a jar of your project.
In Eclipse you can do this with File -> Export.. -> Java -> Jar file.
Then you can import the jar you have created in new projects.

Answer (score 0):

In your project properties there is a way to reference other projects that exist in your workspace.

go to Project > Properties > Java Build Path > Projects > Add