# The import edu cannot be resolved

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using Eclipse Indigo Service Release 2.  I created a project, ProjectName, and added a package, packageName.  I then tried to adde a source file with the following code to the package.

```
package packageName;

import edu.emory.mathcs.jtransforms.fft.DoubleFFT_1D;

public class ClassName {

}
```

I get the error message

```
The import edu cannot be resolved
```

Comment: Did you add a project reference in the `ProjectName` build path for the jar or project containing the `edt.emory...` package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont use Indigo, but in my Eclipse you would do these steps.

Right click project and click properties.

Click Java Build Path tab.

Add JARs or Add External JARs (whichever it is), find JAR and add.

In the Java Build Path you can also add classes and a few other things.

Comment: I get it now.  I was supposed to download the .jar file and include it as you described.  I am new to Java.  Hence my confusion.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Add a project reference in the `ProjectName` build path for the jar or project containing the `edt.emory.mathcs.jtransforms.fft` package.

[Here's a tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4798694/adding-a-reference-between-eclipse-java-projects) on how to do that in Eclipse.

Comment: I went to project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Projects tab -> Add.  It would only let me select a local project.  Thanks.