# How to open app's specific activity from another app in android

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to open a specific activity of app2 from app1.
How do I do that?

Tried: I am able to open app2 using:

```
 Intent paypalIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("package.name);
```

Comment: have you searched for this?, try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18902939/call-activity-in-another-package

Answer (score 0):

You have to try like this

```
Intent launchIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                launchIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
                ComponentName cp = new ComponentName("Your App Packge Name that Contains Register Activity", "Register Activity Name");
                launchIntent.setComponent(cp);

                startActivity(launchIntent);
```

for more info: [Android : Call activity of another application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10960709/android-call-activity-of-another-application)